# OpenShift CLI command to set environment from secret

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

When I exectue this command:

```
oc set env --from=secret/mysqldb dc/hola
```

I get this configuration in deployment environment

[image]

Is there a way to set the deployment configuration using OpenShift CLI so the secret is set in environment from section as shown in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your application you can add it via flag

```sh
oc new-app
```

is the base command

and then you add the `--build-secret` flag.

You final command will look something like this:

```
$ oc new-build \
    openshift/wildfly-101-centos7~https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart.git \
    --context-dir helloworld --build-secret “secret-mvn” \
    --build-config-map "settings-mvn"
```

[Documentation reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/4.9/html/cicd/builds#builds-secrets-overview-updates_creating-build-inputs)